# how to assign array of struct to class variable without memcpy

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm creating a class were doing something with an array of struct, but the problem is I cannot assign array reference to the object.

already trying to find the solution, but only works with copying the entire array to the object variable with `memcpy`, how to do this differently without copying the array?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define arrayLength(array) (size_t)((sizeof array) / (sizeof array[0]))

typedef struct someStruct {
  int id;
  char *name;
} someStruct;

class someClass {
private:
  someStruct *list;

public:
  someClass(someStruct const *const listData) { list = listData; }
};


int main() {
  someStruct list[255] = {
      {1, "one"},
  };

  someClass object(list);

  return 0;
}
```

error: invalid conversion from 'const someStruct*' to 'someStruct*' [-fpermissive]
   someClass(someStruct const *const listData) { list = listData; }

Answer (score 0):

if you are not sure about compiler error message,
here it is in short:

in constructor body you have tried to assign pointer to const value to pointer to value, implicates that if compiler let you, you will try to change const value using pointer and for that you certainly can't use pointer to const. At least not without any special purpose casting.
This is not the only thing in your code sample that should be changed, but you can start from there.

Answer (score 0):

You are supplying a const pointer, then assigning a non-const pointer to that const pointer. The compiler is not letting you downgrade const to non-const.

Make someClass's list a const pointer, or remove the const qualifiers from the initializer parameters.